# Calculate distance between two raw pointers

Tags: rust, ffi

Some C interfaces return pointer to end of buffer. So then I need to convert the range to a slice. But slice can only be created from pointer and count. So how do I get the count.

Writing `end - start` simply gives me `` error: binary operation `-` cannot be applied to type `*mut i8` `` and `std::ptr::PtrExt` only has `offset` method to calculate end from the offset, but not the inverse operation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A raw pointer can be cast to `usize`; you can then perform subtraction on those.

```rust
end as usize - start as usize
```

Comment: I don’t think that adding a method for it would be the right thing to do, but implementing `Sub<*const T, Output = isize>` for `*const T` mightn’t be such a bad idea.

Comment: Note that for x : *mut T, y = x.offset(z), then  (y as usize - x as usize) == z * size_of::<T>() as opposed to being equal to exactly z.

Answer (score 14):

Since 1.47.0 (October 2020), Rust has the [`offset_from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.offset_from) method on the pointer type, allowing you to write:

```rust
let offset: isize = end.offset_from(start);
```

to get the offset from `start` to `end`.